# Dynamic XML Generated from PHP

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic

I have a PHP script that loads XML content dynamically:

```
require_once 'directory/directory/';  
$nice= '1149632';  

$key = 'adf995jdfdfddda44rfg';   
$mixer  = new Live_Products($key);  

$result = $mixer->product($nice)  
->show(array('name','Price'))  
->query();

echo $result
```

This will work fine when it is loaded. But I am trying to use an ajax/jquery script to send the value $nice to the PHP script; and to ultimately send the result back from the dynamically created XML file. I've been trying to figure this out for hours

Here is the ajax Script

```
function sendValues() {  
$("$nice")  
    $.ajax({  
        url: "/myphp.php",  
        data: {str}  
        cache: false  
    });  
}
```

Has anybody done something similar to this concept?

Comment: Try [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) in PHP and `dataType: 'json'` on the jQuery side

Comment: Your `sendValues()` function does not look right at all. Are there any messages in the browser error console? Also, you can't `require` a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass it as a GET param like so...

#### jQuery

```
function sendValues(something) {  
    $.ajax({  
        url: "/myphp.php?nice=" + something,  
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml) {
            // Work with the XML
        }  
    });  
}
```

#### PHP

```
require_once 'directory/directory/';  
$nice= '1149632';  

$key = 'adf995jdfdfddda44rfg';   
$mixer  = new Live_Products($key);  

$result = $mixer->product($_GET['nice'])  
->show(array('name','Price'))  
->query();

// You said it is XML?
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo $result;
```

Comment: I think this is going to work, but when you say //work with XML, would you recommended a get function in order to get the element by tag name?

Comment: @RPM You should be able to use jQuery selectors on the returned XML.